# Find the language of $\sum^*$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages

For the alphabet $\sum = \{0,1\}$, let $A,B,C \subseteq \sum^*$ be the languages below.

$i. A = \{1, 0, 00, 11, 000, 111, 0000, 1111\}$ 
$ii. B = \{w \in \sum^*|||w|| \ge 2 \}$ 
$ii. C = \{w \in \sum^*|||w|| \le 2 \}$

||w|| is the length of the word w.

Determine the following languages of $\sum^*$:

**(a.)** $A \cap B$ 
For this one, I have: $w \in \sum^*$ such that the length of $w \ge 2$, thus $A \cap B = 00, 11, 000, 111, 0000, 1111$. The language of $\sum^* = \{00^n | 1 \le n \le 4\}\cap\{11^n|1\le n \le 4\}$

**(b.)** $B \cup C$
For this one, I have: $w\in \sum^*$ such that the length of $w \le 2$ ot the length of $w \ge 2$, then $B \cup C = \{ 00 | 11 \}.$ The language of $\sum^*=\{0^n | n=2\} \cup \{1^n |n=2\}.$

**(c.)** $A \Delta B$
For this one, I have: $A \Delta B = A \cup B$ (according to a proposition in my study guide). Thus I have, $A \Delta B = \{1,0,00,11,000,111,0000,1111 \}$ or $w \in \sum^*$ such that the length of $w \ge 2$ therefore, $A \Delta B =\{00,11,000,111,0000,1111 \}.$ The language of $\sum^* = \{ 0^n|1 \le n \le 4 \} \cap \{ 1^n | 1 \le n \le 4 \}$ or $\sum^*= \{ 00^n | 1 \le n \le 4 \}\cap \{11^n | 1 \le n \le 4\}.$

I think I am on the right track with these, but any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to misinterpreting $\Sigma^*$ as its first given subset $A$.

$\Sigma^*$ denotes the set of *all* words on alphabet $\Sigma$.

(a) $A\cap B\ =\{00,11,000,111,0000,1111\}$ is correct. Nothing more is needed here. 
(But if you insist, it is rather $\Sigma^*=\{00^n\,:\,1\le n\le 3\}\ \cup\{11^n\,:\,1\le n\le 3\}$.)

(b) $B\cup C$ will give *all* words, i.e. $B\cup C=\Sigma^*$.

(c) $A\Delta B$ usually denotes the *symmetric difference*, containing those elements which are either in $A$ or in $B$ but *not in both*, i.e. $A\Delta B\ =\ (A\cup B)\ \setminus\ (A\cap B)$. Can you describe it now?

Comment: So, is $A \Delta B = \{ 1,0 \}$ with the language being $\sum^* = \{ 1, 0 \}$? @Berci, thanks for you feedback. I appreciate it, and thanks for explaining $\Delta$.

Comment: Another section of my study guide, and in my text book also, states that $A \Delta B = (A-B) \cup (B-A)$. Does this have the same meaning as the one you stated?

Comment: $A\Delta B$ also contains $10,\ 01,\ 110, \dots$ and all words of length $\ge 5$. Yes, the same meaning.

Comment: Why is this true $A \Delta B$ also contains 10, 01, 110,… and all words of length $\ge$ 5? I thought the words were limited to what is in $A$. But, by your answer, that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: So A is a subset of $\sum^*$ and that is why your answer is true, and why $A \Delta B$ also contains 10, 01, 110,...and all words of length $\ge$ 5; none of these values are in $A$.

Comment: Yes, the base set is $\Sigma^*$ and not $A$.